# How to insert xml data into database

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework

I want to insert XML data into database, but some fields are not inserted
I have a XML data like this

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [person-id] => 4562
    [name] => gopi 
    [category] => working 
    [lead-commission] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
    [expire-date] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
    [manufactur-date] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
    [type] => medicine [sale-commission] => 1.00%
)
```

my code to insert into database

```
foreach($xml->link AS $value)
{
    $data['person-id']= $value->{'person-id'};
    $data['name']= $value->{'name'};  
    $data['category']= $value->{'category'};
    $data['lead-commission']= $value->{'lead-commission'};
    $data['expire-date']= $value->{'expire-date'};
    $data['manufacture-date']= $value->{'manufactur-date'};
    $data['type']= $value->{'type'};
    $data['sale-commission']= $value->{'sale-commission'};
}
```

But I am not able to insert the **lead-commission**, **expire-date**, **manufacture-date** in my database can you please help me how to insert this fields

Comment: Hopefully some robots here will be able to work out your paste and help you ;)

Comment: Those properties appear to be (potentially empty) XML nodes. Can you give an example of the XML itself?

Comment: As you can clearly see from your dump, `lead-commission, expire-date, manufacture-date` are XML objects... You must go deeper!

Comment: Try to print the `lead-commission` object first.

Comment: can show the XML file data once...

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function and convert the XML to PHP Array

> http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-xml-to-array-in-php-xml2array/

Then use "`print_r()`" to see the fields and array structure. Accordingly insert the data.

Hope the link provided helps